# How do I make my CSS link up to files in different directories

Tags: php, html, css, file

I am trying to organize my files for my website: The file structure is folders: css | fonts | images | includes | Admin | user | Member - the user folder currently contains the index.php and index.html, search.php, etc. The includes contains the forms I'm trying to get to work with my css.

The css file is inside the css folder. I've tried ../css/style.css and I've tried ..css/style.css and I've tried ../../css/style.css. Nothing I do renders my css. Here is a screen shot of my folder set up:

[image: FILE SET UP]

Comment: Your css file is named web289.css, not style.css

Comment: I was just using style as a example. I am using web289.css in my files. Thanks for trying to help though. This is very confusing and it should work.

Comment: You should provide exactly what you tried, otherwise you only send people on wrong ways. I was about to vote to close this question as a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/web289.css" />`  as css link as the name of your css is not `style.css`

Comment: I was just using style as an example. I am using just what you've written. ../css/web289.css. Thanks so much for trying to help me though. It's very confusing. It definitely should work.!!!

Comment: Right click and view the source of your code in the browser. then click the link where the css file is linked. If the css code is shown it is alright if it shows 404 not found then there is problem with your css location.

Comment: Doing this shows me my css, that's why I don't understand why it's not working!!!! Thank you again. God bless you.

Comment: Thank you. After I right clicked and viewed the source and clicked on the CSS, it started working. I don't know what that did, but it's working and I thank you so much. God bless you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to import css in your file. It depends on what language you are using. like for HTML you need to write following code:
`<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssfilename.css">
</head>`

Answer (score 1):

The name of your stylesheet isn't style.css, its web289.css, you should use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/web289.css">
```

Comment: I was only using style as an example, in my project I'm using web289.css. Thanks so much though.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should define or structure your **static data**.

```
/project_folder
    |-- /static
            |-- /css
                  |-- style.css
                  |-- web289.css
            |-- /js
            |-- /images
            |-- /fonts
```

And this is how you should define static data **in your code**.
- Define somewhere (in config) your projects path
- And then always use relative paths for static file

**Images:**

```
<img src="/static/images/homepage/xyz.jpg" />
```

**CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/web289.css"/>
```

So answering to your question,
- Keep all the static da.ta in a single folder (as explained above)
- Include it in your code starting from a **slash** `/` and then continuing with the **folder name** and **file name**

But still if you want to continue with it you can simply use,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/web289.css" />
```

**Meaning**, move one folder up there you'll find a css folder inside which you've your css file `web289.css`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've tried this and it's not working. I really WISH it were. Everything is working except the css. Thank you for trying to help me though.

Comment: "always" is such a strong word.

Comment: Yaah, because this is the best way to define static data. Whats you call?

Comment: It started working after I right clicked and checked the css. Thank God and God bless everyone here who tried to help me. I am so happy it is working.